# Heroku: scaling for amazon mturk - is this feasible? What type of

Tags: flask, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, mechanicalturk

If you have a free verified account on heroku and you create a project, is it reasonable to assume that provides enough computational power for an online experiment to be deployed on crowdsourcing resources such as Amazon Mechanical Turk?

We had an online experiment developed on heroku. We have deployed this on mturk twice to a pool of 50 subjects and we never had traffic issues. I have had a free verified account up to this point.

Last night, when we tried to deploy this on mturk to a pool of 500 subjects, many complained that the site wasn't working and we had to cancel data collection. Now I'm left wondering if Heroku can actually provide the resources for this online experiment to be able to handle the web traffic it's going to get.

To give a layout of what processing demands the web application makes... The online experiment is really a Flask application that only consists of 3 pages. 1 page is a simple homepage. The 2nd page contains the experimental phase of the app. Upon being loaded, the second webpage executes a view function in Flask that creates 75 simple images in matplotlib. These images are preloaded using the Jspsych framework in Javascript. The 3rd page is a simple page that contains an embedded qualtrics survey.

My procfile contains the following.

```
heroku ps:scale web=2

web gunicorn -w 4 app_dir.experiment:app
```

However, only 1 dyno is shown as active, and I don't know how I can get more than one dyno. I've read about the limits imposed on free accounts on  heroku compared to others, it seems like free verified accounts can only have 1 web dyno and 2 concurrent one-off dynos. So I'm trying to see if this problem can be mitigated by me upgrading to either Hobby or Standard dynos. Even then, I'm not sure if this is really a fool's errand or not. I don't know how many dynos I actually need to be aiming for to handle the web traffic I'm expecting.

So I wanted to ask this question to try to confirm whether or not I should still be trying to host this online experiment on Heroku or not. If so, how can I increase the number of dynos for my application? Do I need to upgrade my membership to Hobby or Standard? (these are pricey)

Answer (score 0):

A lot will depend on how many of the participants arrive at the same time. If it's just one person coming in every couple of minutes, the basic account should be able to handle it. But, if your survey is popular, and you open it to all 500 at once, Mechanical Turk will allow that many to arrive all at once. And that could cause problems.

If you are using the MTurk API, as a possible work around, you could initially create your survey with 10 participants. After those are done, you can call [CreateAdditionalAssignmentsForHIT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CreateAdditionalAssignmentsForHITOperation.html) and add another 10, continuing to do so until you reach 500. MTurk will make sure that if someone did one of the first 10, they are ineligible for the next tranche you offer.